# Cómo resolver un problema de caracteres especiales después del método regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

He visto una interesante estos días para estudiar francés con una interfaz sencilla usando tkinker. Mientras estoy estudiando esta biblioteca, he decidido hacer mi propia versión, pero esta vez para aprender español. Antes de usar tkinker se requiere un documento csv con palabras frecuentes. Estoy usando este documento para hacer-lo:

https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords/blob/master/content/2018/es/es_50k.txt

Mi primer objetivo es filtrar este archivo txt y crear un archivo csv sin los números. Aquí encontré mi primer problema. Cuando las palabras pasan el "filtro de regex", algunas letras "cambian"

```
import re
from pandas import*
import string

language = "spanish"

list_not_letters = [
     ('&aacute', 'á'), ('&agrave', 'à'), ('&atilde', 'ã'), ('&Atilde', 'Ã'), ('&acirc', 'â'), ('&Acirc', 'Â'), ('&Agrave', 'À'),
    ('&eacute', 'é'), ('&Eacute', 'É'), ('&ecirc', 'ê'), ('&Ecirc', 'Ê'), ('&iacute', 'í'), ('&Iacute', 'Í'),
 ('&oacute', 'ó'), ('&Oacute', 'Ó'), ('&otilde', 'õ'), ('&Otilde', 'Õ'),
 ('&uacute', 'ú'), ('&Uacute', 'Ú'), ('&ugrave', 'ù'), ('&Ugrave', 'Ù'),
 ('&ccedil', 'ç'), ('&Ccedil', 'Ç'),  ('&ntilde', 'ñ'), ('&Ntilde', 'Ñ')
]

alfabeth = string.ascii_lowercase

words_list = [language]
with open("es_50k.txt", "r") as file:
    words = file.read()
    words = words.split() # split the lines using spaces as parameter

for word in words:
        if word == re.sub('[0-9]', '', word): # verify if word contains number
           word.split() #divide the word in letters
           for letter in word:
               if letter not in alfabeth: # verify if it is a letter
                   especial_letter = letter # if it's not a letter, so it's a especial char.
                   index_letter = list_not_letters.index(especial_letter)# use it to find the index in the non letters list
                   letter.replace(list_not_letters[index_letter][1], list_not_letters[index_letter][0])# replace the first value of the tuple for the second
           word = ''.join(word)
           words_list.append(word)
    data_list = DataFrame(words_list)
    data_list.to_csv('only_words.csv', index=False)
```

Intentando solucionar el problema, he creado una lista con tuplas, cuando el primer elemento es el "carácter extraño" y el segundo es el que debería estar en el csv. Después de eso, lo he leído todo, intentando organizarlo y comentarlo, parte por parte, para asegurarme de que no era un problema tipográfico.

Entonces tuve esa mensaje de error:

Rastreo (última llamada más reciente): Archivo "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\word_guide\main.py", línea 27, en index_letter = list_not_letters.index(especial_letter)# úselo para encontrar el índice en la lista sin letras ValueError: 'Ã' no está en la lista

Para resolver a eso último erro, cambié:

```
index_letter = list_not_letters.index(especial_letter)
```

por

```
for index,y in enumerate(list_not_letters) :
  if especial_letter in y:
    index_letter = index
```

El erro sumio pero agora todas las veces que la "letter" no es parte del "alfabeth", substituye por 'Ã' o algo de errado ocurre.
Incluso sabiendo dónde reside el problema, todavía no sé cómo solucionarlo. Tengo muchas publicaciones interesantes aquí, probé algunas ideas de videos de YouTube, pero hasta ahora ninguna funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te ocurre es que te esta mostrando los caracteres no ASCII como su respectiva entidad de carácter. Esto mas que un problema derivado de aplicar regex es un problema de codificación. Por las trazas de tu excepciones, usas Windows, UTF-8 es el estándar en la Web, en la mayoría de editores de texto, en Linux, Mac o Android, pero Windows... La codificación usada por defecto por `Open` depende de la plataforma (`locale.getpreferredencoding()`), lo mas probable en tu caso es que simplemente estés usando una codificación incorrecta para leer y escribir el archivo. Espero que [PEP 686](https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/) termine en parte con esta pesadilla. Simplemente usa el parámetro `encoding` de `open()` y especifica que use UTF-8.

Aparte de eso, si solo quieres obtener las palabras eliminando la frecuencia (el número después de cada una), creo que te estas complicando mucho. El archivo es ya un csv válido (de dos columnas, sin header y usando espacios como separador), basta con leer la columna con las palabras e ignorar la otra:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords/raw/master/content/2018/es/es_50k.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True, usecols = [0], names=["spanish"], encoding='utf-8')
```

Con ello ya tienes un dataframe con una columna con todas tus palabras:

```
>>> df["spanish"]
0                  de
1                 que
2                  no
3                   a
4                  la
             ...     
49995        auditiva
49996          rennie
49997    involucraría
49998         joaquim
49999      hormonales
Name: words, Length: 50000, dtype: object
```

Por lo que solo quedaría generar el nuevo csv:

```
df.to_csv('only_words.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

O sin necesidad de Pandas, simplemente:

```
with (open('es_50k.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile,
        open('only_words.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile):
    outfile.write("spanish\n")
    outfile.writelines((f"{line.split()[0]}\n" for line in infile))
```